# Power BI Time Saver Tip: Change blanks to nulls in transforms (simple cases)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

Is blank the same as null? And how do I force a Replace Values transform to use null (the null "type") instead of blank or a text value.  I just want to replace "-" with the proper true *null* so that later functions will work!

Answer (score 1):

Blank is not the same as null - blank represents an empty string value ("").

*null* is the database equivalent of "unknown".

Several functions depend on getting this value right, depending on what you are putting in the report.  So when you are querying a data source, you may need to convert to *null* and not blank or 0 for later transforms or uses to work properly.

But if you type NULL (all caps) as the replacement value, it puts the text/string "NULL" in the field, rather than the italicized indicator that the field is truly *null*.

**SOLUTION: in the find/replace window of Replace Value step, type in lower-case "null" and it will automatically detect that you meant the *null* "type" and not the string.**

Hopefully this saves some n00bs like me a ton of googling on a simple subject.